# Create a new Navigation and add it to the left navigation bar in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, navigation, flat, sitecollection

In my company we try to make a Parent Child Navigation of a flat site collection(in SharePoint 2010). Meaning we just want to add new pages to the site collection instead of creating new site collections. We do this so we can easily reach all the documents at one place with different information on the other pages.

I would love to post an image on how I would like to have it but I haven't got enough of points to do that.

We know that we have to override the left Navigation bar but then we are lost. Do you know how we could solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  ***[Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matjazperpar/archive/2008/12/17/how-to-create-custom-navigation-menu-in-sharepoint-with-xml-data-source.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)*** was one part of my answer. It shows how you solve my problem in SP designer for SP 2007 and whit some small thinking of your own you will solve the small differences that you will fined in SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the navigation for the quick launch using [SPNavigationNodeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms427791.aspx) and look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb897739%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on customising navigation and associated providers (it's too much info to copy to an answer)

Comment: I'm afraid that this wasn't what I was looking for. I don't want to show all the child links all the time and I need a way to apply this when a user creates a new page to the site that needs to bee added into the navigation view for this department.